# How to minimize the number of functions to be projected on

Tags: optimization

I have a set of functions $f_i,\, i=1,2,\ldots,n$ defined on an interval $[a,b]$,
and a function $F$ also defined on $[a,b]$. I would like to project F on a subset of functions $f_i$ so that the number of $f_i$ used to represent $F$ is minimum, but $\|F-\sum\limits^k_{i=1}f_iw_i\|\rightarrow0$, where $w_i$ are some weights.
Any help on this problem or a reference leading to its solution is very welcome.

Thank you.

Karla

Comment: What do you mean when you say "but $\|F-\sum\limits^k_{i=1}f_iw_i\|\rightarrow0$"?

Comment: I just wanted to say that the difference between $F$ and its projection is small for the minimum number of $f_i$, which is denoted by $k$.

Comment: The problem can also be reformulated as a function expansion problem:
expand $F$ into a sum $\sum\limits^k_{i=1}f_iw_i$ so that $\|F-\sum\limits^k_{i=1}f_iw_i\|\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to sample the functions $F$ and $f_i$ at a bunch of points in the interval $[a,b]$, obtaining  vectors $G$ and $g_i$.  Then minimize $\| w \|_1 + \alpha \| G - \sum_{i=1}^n g_i w_i \|$ with respect to $w$.  (Here $\alpha > 0$ is a parameter you can tune.)  That's a convex problem so it could be solved efficiently.

A key point is that by penalizing the $1$-norm of $w$ we encourage $w$ to be sparse.  So most of the components of the optimal $w$ will be equal to $0$.

Comment: I've tried the idea with fminsearch in MATLAB, but the result is poor.

Comment: @Karla You could try solving the optimization problem using CVX, which might do better.  How many sample points did you use?  Did you try many different values of $\alpha$?  What about the results is poor?

Comment: I used 243 sample points and different values of $\alpha$ but it didn't help. The poor results mean a large value of $\|F-\sum\limits^n_{i=1}f_iw_i\|$, which is far a way from being optimal. Perhaps, I should try CVX.

Comment: What's your value of $n$?

Comment: $n=243$ and the length of the vectors $G$ and $g_i$ is also 243.

Comment: I see.  Is $\|G - \sum_{i=1}^n g_i w_i \|$ small, at least?  When $\alpha$ is large, if the optimization problem is being solved correctly, then $\|G - \sum_{i=1}^n g_i w_i \|$ should be nearly $0$.

Comment: $\| G - \sum_{i=1}^n g_i w_i \|$ is around several hundreds.

Comment: Assuming the vectors $g_i$ are linearly independent, you should be able to pick the $w_i$ so that $G - \sum_{i=1}^n g_i w_i$ is exactly $0$.  As a sanity check, you could try just minimizing $G - \sum_{i=1}^n g_i w_i$ by itself, and check that the minimum value is $0$.  Also, you could try putting the vectors $g_i$ into the columns of a matrix $M$.  Let w = M\G ; (using Matlab notation), and check that $G - \sum_{i=1}^n g_i w_i$ is $0$.

Comment: Of course, it is 0, but I'd like to have the minimum number of $g_i$.

Comment: Yes, just a sanity check.  I'd be interested in seeing the functions $F$ and $f_i$ explicitly, if it's not hard to write them.  Where does this problem come from, out of curiosity?

Comment: The problem is that I have neither $F$ nor $f_i$ in an explicit form. They are just a bunch of numbers. I can send you the data if you'd like.